# select multiple tables sql in vb.net datagrid view - sql &vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to select multiple tables in mysql and then return it to a `datagridview` to my application. The SQL query downunder, doesn't work. Is the sql wrong? I have two tables called "`bruker`" & "`blodgiver`" in mysql

```
Dim searchQuery As String = "SELECT bruker INNER JOIN blodgiver WHERE CONCAT(bruker_id, fornavn, etternavn, epost, personnummer) like '%" & valueToSeach & "%'"

Dim command As New MySqlCommand(searchQuery, MysqlConn)
Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
Dim table As New DataTable()

adapter.Fill(table)

DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide on clause.

```
SELECT * FROM bruker br INNER JOIN blodgiverbd on bd.<link_column1> = db.<link_column2>  WHERE CONCAT(bruker_id, fornavn, etternavn, epost, personnummer) like '%" & valueToSeach & "%'"
```

Comment: Hi,
I get an error trying to run this fix in my application. Do i have to change anything in my sql code? Thanks for the help.

I tried to run the code like this:
Dim searchQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM bruker br INNER JOIN blodgiverbd on bd.<bruker> = db.<blodgiver>  WHERE CONCAT(bruker_id, fornavn, etternavn, epost, personnummer) like '%" & valueToSeach & "%'"

Comment: It is just a sample. It must be adapted to your needs, since <link...> are just placeholder for your columns that will be used to join those two tables

Comment: In the link_colum1 can i declare = "bruker"

Comment: Let say that you have bruker table with column a,b,c and blogdriver with columns e,f,g then depending on what columns do you want to join the table you specify them in ON clause. ..ON bruker.a = blogdriver.e. Where a and e could be primary keys or whatever columsn you want ot join those tables